# Is Exception Enrichment a viable pattern?

Tags: java, error-handling

I recently came across an article by Jakob Jenkov about Enrichable Exceptions. I really like the idea!

I've been a Java developer for 4 years, and I still get really annoyed trying to figure out what to do with all the SQLExcepions, IOExceptions, and random exceptions thrown by third-party libraries. I end up putting so much thought into when is it appropriate tho rethrow the exception, or wrap it one a custom exception, but if I write a custom exception, then were do I put it? In the same package as the class I'm writing, or in a central "exceptions" package? I've even toyed with declaring custom exceptions an inner classes since they often seem pretty one-off.

Anyways, Jenkov's idea is outlined here: 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-enrichment.html

Using a single enrichable exception as he outlines seems really attractive to me as it seems to pretty handily side-step most of my frustrations. But I don't think I've ever seen it used in any of the libraries I've used. Is there a reason for that? Is there a major flaw to this approach that I'm missing?

Simple Summary:

```
public class AppException extends Exception{
    public AppException(String errCode, String context, String userMessage, Throwable t){}

    public AppException(String, errCode, String context, String userMessage) {}

    public void addInfo(String errCode, String context, String userMessage){}
}

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MyApp app = new MyApp();

            app.start(args[0], args[1]);        
    }

    public void start(String username, String password) {
        try {
            User user = loginController.login(username, password);
        } catch (AppException e) {
            if (e.getCode().contains("INCORRECT_PASSWORD")) {
                logger.warn(e.toString(), e);
                // Prompt user for new password and try again.
            } else {
                logger.error(e.toString(), e);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unexpected Exception.", e);
        }
    }
}

public class LoginController {
    public User login(String username, String password) {
        try {
            if (userDao.checkPassword(username, password)) {
                // Build and return the user object.
            }
        } catch (AppExcption e) {
            e.addInfo("LOGIN_FAILED", "LoginController", "Failed to login");
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

public class UserDao {
    public boolean checkPassword(String username, String password) {
        try {
            // Check the password against the DB.

            if (passwordIsCorrect) {
                return true;
            } else {
                throw new AppException("INCORRECT_PASSWORD", "UserDao", "Password for user " + username + " is not correct.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new AppException("DB_CONNECTION_ERR", "UserDao", "Can't connect to Database", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Implementation of the exception class is available in Jenkov's article. In the above code example, if the DB is unreachable the error log would look like:

```
[LOGIN_FAILED, LogginController], [DB_CONNECTION_ERR, UserDao]
[LOGIN_FAILED, LogginController]: Failed to login
[DB_CONNECTION_ERR, UserDao]: Can't connect to Database
<<SQLException stacktrace here>>
```

But if an incorrect password was entered it would be:

```
[LOGIN_FAILED, LogginController], [INCORRECT_PASSWORD, UserDao]
[LOGIN_FAILED, LogginController]: Failed to login
[DB_CONNECTION_ERR, UserDao]: Password for user [passed in username] is not correct.
```

I'd probably add an enum or something for the error codes to make selective handling easier, and to ensure they are actually unique. But the error message gives a very clear concise view of what when wrong, and it's easy to add additional information as an error climes the call stack so that a developer would be able to recreate the error.

So to repeat my question. Why isn't this used more widely? Is there a major flaw in this approach that I'm missing?

Comment: Do your own research, I do not believe that anyone can objectively answer this question, and so every answer will be just an opinion, this is not a good technical question.